# How to use qcut and groupby to ensure all bins are present in each day

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I am using qcut combined with groupby on a df with multi-index, the first index is a date.
The desired behaviour is, that every day, I get my 'target' variable quantiles, so that for every day my quantiles variable has an equal number of observations in each of the quantiles, below num_ranks is equal to 5, so it should range from 0 to 4). But for some days I only get values up to 3. I cannot produce a min example because in my min examples it worked fine, it is with the larger dataset that I have this issue for 1% of the days. Is there anything in the arguments that I need to change to guarantee that every day has all 5 quantiles present?

```
df['quantiles'] = df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values(0))['target'].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q=num_ranks, labels=False, precision=0, duplicates='drop'))
```

Comment: When I set duplicates to 'raise' I get warnings about a number of duplicates. Is it possible that some of them are dropped and that is why I end up with not all quantiles?